# Dealing with JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON response as such:

```
{
  "SiteInfo": [
    {
      "'LOB03023D'": {
        "errorText": "Success",
        "status": "1",
        "parameterList": {
          "aloha_mask": "255.255.255.0",
          "beta_mask": "255.255.255.224",
          "omega_mask": "0",
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "Error Text": null,
  "API RequestID": "11",
  "Status": 1,
  "Username": "NMS@internal.com",
  "TransactionID": "1467626",
  "Error Code": null,
  "GetSiteInfoTimeStamp": "2017-02-23 21:32:42"
}
```

In my script after loading the response as such:

```
ubdataset = json.loads(response.text)
```

How can I access only the 'aloha_mask' field?

The following did not work for me:

```
aloha = ubdataset['SiteInfo']['LOB03023D']['parameterList'][0]['aloha_mask']
```

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: " 'LOB03023D' " has double and single quotes, maybe that is the Problem

Comment: "it did not work" is **not an adequate problem statement**

Comment: The value of the `'SiteInfo'` key is a list, which you didn't notice.

Comment: print ubdataset["SiteInfo"][0]["'LOB03023D'"]['parameterList']['aloha_mask']

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to this:

```
aloha = ubdataset['SiteInfo'][0]["'LOB03023D'"]['parameterList']['aloha_mask']
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Can you briefly point me to to a document or explain the need for [0] where it is?

Comment: SiteInfo is the key, and the value is the list.  You are accessing the 0th element in you list.

Comment: [0] in this case being LOB03023D?

Comment: @telecomToperl why don't you try this out yourself and see? You will discover that you are working with a `list` of `dict`s

Answer (score 0):

Parameter list is not a list, your statement should be:

```
aloha = ubdataset['SiteInfo'][0]["'LOB03023D'"]['parameterList']['aloha_mask']
```

Although the request is not valid json the last element in parameterList has a comma that should not be there.

Comment: You need to quote the `LOB03023D` part. The single quotes are part of the key.